# Setting NSString in one class, calling it in another class

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, nsstring, global

So, I'm trying to set the value of `NSString` in one class, and then, call that `NSString` in another class and load it into a label.

I have declared the string in `Class A` as a nonatomic, retained property. In one method, I set the value of the string.

In `Class B`, I import `Class A`, alloc, and init `Class A`, and then I try to set the label text with:

```
ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
label.text = classA.string
```

However, every time I do this, the label remains blank.

So, why is my property not retaining the value I assign it in the method? The `NSString` gets it's value in a tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Thanks!

**EDIT** I realize I made a mistake while typing the code snippet above, and I left out the property "string" on the object "classA". Forgive me. The comments below were somewhat unnecessary, but thank you for pointing out my mistake. For the record, I know how objects, classes, and properties work.

Comment: Huh? That doesn't make any sense.  Why are you assigning an instance of a class to the text property of a label?  There are no strings in your code snippet.

Comment: You've got two different instances of ClassA.  Each has its own copies of any strings that are assigned to instance variables.  So creating a new ClassA will not in any fashion fetch a string stored in a different instance of ClassA.  But beyond that, your code above is nonsense -- you can't assign a non-string (and "classA" is not a string) to label text.

Comment: (In other words you don't know WTF you're doing, and you need to go back to school, to learn a little bit about objects and classes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a property, you should be able to do it by saying `label.text = classA.propertyName` (whatever you named your property.)

For example let's say in `ClassA` that you created `NSString` `*stringToOutput`, then in `Class B` after instantiating `Class A`, you'd state that `label.text = classA.stringToOutput`.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I mean, yes, that makes sense, and it is what I am doing, but I am still getting blank label fields. All that works is if I go into the class where the NSStrings are generated and  use: `classB.label setText:stringToOutput` for some reason, it won't work to call the declared strings in the other class, they return blank.

Answer (score 0):

`label.text = classA.somePropertyThatIsAString;`